# Bluemix: how to monitor and record app availability over long periods

Tags: monitoring, ibm-cloud, availability

Does anyone have experience monitoring and recording Bluemix availability over weeks to months?

My initial plan to do this was to use the Monitoring and Analytics service to send event notifications to my email which I could collect and process. However, from what I understand, event notifications are only sent when things go bad (e.g. when the app is down, or under-performing), but not when the apps return to normal. This is enough for recording on what days apps have gone down, but ideally I would like finer granularity, i.e. exactly how many minutes it was down for.

With all this information I would then like to go and make a chart of Bluemix's availability each month. Are there other options available to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Monitoring & Analytics service does send closing events when the app returns to normal.

Answer (score 0):

If you want generate a report, you could create a specific application (monitoring application) that does tests on that services\application (for example for a DB service you could test if the connection is ok or ko; for application you could test the speed\status code ), store all information in DB and generate the report. 
You could use **embeddable Reporting** to create a report application as you want (https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/EmbeddableReporting/index.html#gettingstartedtemplate).